# Como padronizo as respostas de uma api java spring-boot?

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

Estou desenvolvendo uma api spring boot e gostaria de padronizar as respostas dela, quando meu front-end faz uma requisição ela me devolve um json com dois tipos de formato nos objetos internos

Ex:

```
[
    {
        "id": 22,
        "patient": null,
        "dentist": {
            "userId": "DTN-101001",
            "document": "101001",
            "name": "Roberto",
            "surname": "Lakhroos",
            "email": "lakhross@gmail.com.br",
            "telephone": "1140028922",
            "cellphone": "11941170146",
            "expertise": "Cirurgia",
            "status": true
        },
        "dateTime": "2022-06-18 08:00:00",
        "procedure": null,
        "employee": {
            "userId": "EPL-12345697810",
            "document": "12345697810",
            "name": "Roberto",
            "surname": "Lakhroos",
            "email": "lakhross@gmail.com.br",
            "telephone": "1140028922",
            "cellphone": "11941170146",
            "expertise": null,
            "status": true
        },
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "patient": null,
        "dentist": "DTN-101001",
        "dateTime": "2022-06-18 09:00:00",
        "procedure": null,
        "employee": "EPL-12345697810",
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "patient": null,
        "dentist": "DTN-101001",
        "dateTime": "2022-06-18 10:00:00",
        "procedure": null,
        "employee": "EPL-12345697810",
        "status": true
    }
]
```

Na primeira vez que um dentist ou employee aparecem eles vem completos, mas quando deveria aparecer os mesmos dados de novo a api devolve só o userId, como faço para que a resposta venha sempre com todos os dados?

Função no Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/list/{status}")
public List<Consult> findByStatus(@PathVariable("status") Boolean status) {
    LOGGER.info("Search consults by status - " + status);

    return this.consultRepository.findAllByStatus(status);
}
```

Função no Repository:

```
@Query("SELECT u from Consult u where u.status = :status")
public List<Consult> findAllByStatus(@Param("status") Boolean status);
```

Atributos da entidade:

```
@Table(name = "consults")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Consult {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_cpf")
    private Patient patient;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dentist_id", nullable = false)
    private User dentist;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "procedure_id")
    private Procedure procedure;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    private User employee;

    private Boolean status;

    //Getters, Setters, Contructors...
}
```

Código completo https://github.com/Fatec-ID-Grupo-2-2023/tgs-api-hk

Answer (score -2):

O problema é precisamente como Jackson trabalha serializando o objeto java para JSON. Quando usamos `@JsonIdentityInfo` para resolver o problema de dependência cíclica no grafo de objetos, estamos forçando o mecanismo de serialização a serializar a primeira ocorrência do objeto Java em JSON e a ocorrência subsequente a ser substituída pelo id gerado.

A solução pode ser criar um objeto que estende `SimpleObjectIdResolver`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerator.IdKey;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdResolver;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.SimpleObjectIdResolver;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class DedupingObjectIdResolver extends SimpleObjectIdResolver {
    @Override
    public void bindItem(IdKey id, Object ob) {
        if (_items == null) {
            _items = new HashMap<>();
        }
        _items.put(id, ob);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectIdResolver newForDeserialization(Object context) {
        return new DedupingObjectIdResolver();
    }
}
```

E anotar em seu relacionamento @ManyToOne com @JsonIdentifyInfo e aplicando a classe resolvedora recém criada.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
        property="userId", 
        scope = User.class, 
        resolver = DedupingObjectIdResolver.class
)
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
private User employee;
```